# Unitary operator as cayley transform of self adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Using functional calculus of bounded functions is easy to see that the application of the function $t \to \frac{t-i}{t+i}$ to any self-adjoint operator $T$ gives a unitary operator $U$ whose spectrum does not contain the point 1.

Rudin states in chapter $13$ the converse: that any unitary operator whose spectrum does not contain $1$ is obtained in this way. However, I think this cannot be proved using bounded functions since the function that one would need to find such $T$ has to take the unitary circle minus $1$ to the real line and hence is not bounded.

Is Rudin wrong in this statement?

Comment: See here https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Spectral_Theory_of_Families_of_Self_Adjo/euH6CAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=unitary+operator+whose+spectrum+does+not+contain+1&pg=PA2&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Also, see here https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Operator_Algebras/XHLj7bz8hOIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=unitary+operator+whose+spectrum+does+not+contain+1&pg=PA115&printsec=frontcover

Comment: This function will be bounded when restricted to the spectrum of $U$.

Comment: You are missing some $i$s in the formula. However: If $1$ is not in the spectrum of the unitary, then the _inverse_ of the Cayley Transform is is bounded on the spectrum of the unitary and you can use the bounded functional calculus.

Comment: I don't think the inverse is bounded even if 1 is not in the spectrum. The function certainly doesn't takes on the infinity value, but is not bounded, it takes on any value no matter how large.

Comment: The.spectrum is compact and the function is continuous, hence bounded on $\text{sp}(U)$.

Comment: You are right, the key fact is that the spectrum is closed or, in another words, the resolvent set is open. Hence the spectrum not containing the point 1 implies actually not containing a neighbour around 1, and hence the inverse Cayley transform is bounded.